# Expo.io using React Native - "Super expression must be either null or a function"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

Code:

```
    import React from 'react'
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component(){
  render(){
    return(
     <View> </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Why is this returning an error? I am using version 42.00 on Expo.io and my browser is fully updated.

Answer (score 1):

You've accidentally added `()` after `React.Component`. It should be likeso:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return(
     <View> </View>
    )
  }
}
```